# Saving slug name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I use to save my page's title.

```
add_action('cred_save_data', 'add_job_data_action',10,2);
function add_job_data_action($post_id, $form_data) {
    $title = trim(strip_tags(do_shortcode('[wpv-view name="Job Counter"]')));
    if ($form_data['id']==4851) {
        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $my_post['post_title'] = $title;
        $my_post['slug'] = $title;
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
}
```

I want the slug to be the same as the title, but it doesn't seem to get it. It's always saved as autodraft-xx

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $title`? What is the result? I assume the post does get saved?

Comment: We must supose that you using this? http://wp-types.com/home/cred/

Comment: Yes, i'm using toolset from wptypes

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) is where you can get all parameters

```
'post_name'      => [ <the name> ] // The name (slug) for your post
```

Hopefully someone learns something too!